# Failed to include internals in a relocate, trying to recover

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When relocating a number of working copies I apparently failed to click the 'include externals' button for a couple of them, and now it's not clear how to recover. I've tried running an in-place 'switch' with the externals included but it had no effect. I'm tempted to do an in-place 'relocate' including externals, but the warnings are harsh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion keeps track of externals via a property called `svn:externals`. What you need to do is locate the directory where this external property is located. Unfortunately, this is where the command line version of Subversion has a big advantage over TortoiseSVN. Fortunately, most of the time, the external is located under the directory where the `svn:externals` property is located.

Find the directory where the `svn:externals` property is defined. Then right click on that directory to get the context menu, From the context menu, select TortoiseSVN->Properties. This brings up the Properties dialog box. Find the `svn:externals` property, and double click on it. You'll now get another dialog box where you can edit the external property itself.

Click on the *Edit...* button, and update the property.

### A slight suggestion

External properties can contain the entire URL, but you may also specify the URL in relationship to the directory itself.

For example, we have a project directory called `ivy.dir` that contains all of our Ivy definitions (and other plugins such as FindBugs) that are used by all projects. These projects are suppose to include this `ivy.dir` under their root directory. These other projects are sister project directories to ivy.dir.

We could have defined our external this way:

```
http://svn/rsvp/trunk/ivy.dir ivy.dir
```

The problem is when I branch the project, the `ivy.dir` is still under trunk and will get trunk's changes. This is probably not what I want. Plus, if I relocate the entire structure or use a new server, I'll lose the external definition -- just like you did.

Instead, I define this external this way:

```
../ivy.dir ivy.dir
```

This says that the external is located one directory up, and then under the `ivy.dir` project directory. Now, when I branch, or if I redefine the protocol used, or move my server, my external definition doesn't change.

Since you're editing your external definition anyway, you may want to keep in mind to redefine the external in relationship to the repository's directory where it's defined, and not the absolute URL.